# MPU6050 motion driver library function call cause hardfault exception

Tags: c, embedded, stm32, sensors, mpu6050

Hi I'm try to use mpu6050 on my stm32 project.

I copy the motion driver library from [SparkFun_MPU-9250-DMP_Arduino_Library](https://github.com/sparkfun/SparkFun_MPU-9250-DMP_Arduino_Library) and replace arduino function like arduino_i2c_write to stm32 write function. The replace part work fine. The stm32 board did write bytes into the imu and read from it.

However, when I try to setup the dmp funtion and use the `mpu_load_firmware` function, I encouter a weird situation.

```
int mpu_load_firmware(unsigned short length, const unsigned char *firmware,
    unsigned short start_addr, unsigned short sample_rate)
{
    unsigned short ii;
    unsigned short this_write;
    /* Must divide evenly into st.hw->bank_size to avoid bank crossings. */
#define LOAD_CHUNK  (16)

    unsigned char cur[LOAD_CHUNK], tmp[2];

    if (st.chip_cfg.dmp_loaded)
        /* DMP should only be loaded once. */
        return -1;

    if (!firmware)
        return -1;
    for (ii = 0; ii < length; ii += this_write) {
        this_write = min(LOAD_CHUNK, length - ii);
        if (mpu_write_mem(ii, this_write, (unsigned char*)&(firmware[ii])))
            return -1;
        if (mpu_read_mem(ii, this_write, cur))
            return -1;
        if (memcmp(firmware+ii, cur, this_write))
            return -2;
    }

    /* Set program start address. */
    tmp[0] = start_addr >> 8;
    tmp[1] = start_addr & 0xFF;
    if (i2c_write(st.hw->addr, st.reg->prgm_start_h, 2, tmp))
        return -1;

    st.chip_cfg.dmp_loaded = 1;
    st.chip_cfg.dmp_sample_rate = sample_rate;
    return 0;
}
```

When the code run to the line `if (mpu_write_mem(ii, this_write, (unsigned char*)&(firmware[ii])))`, it cause a hardfault. And I found out that the code cannnot call the `mpu_write_mem` function porperly. When I start to step in the function, the hardfault exception immediately occurred. I cannot figure it out what cause the exception and how to fix it.

I've checked the pointer, `&(firmware[ii])`, address, it looks just fine. But the weired thing is that in the `mpu_write_mem` function, the argument value all differ from the `mpu_load_firmware` function.(`mem_addr` != `ii`, `length` != `this_write`, ...) I'm not sure if this cause the exception or the other way around.

Can anyone give me some idea? Thank you very much ~~

Here is the `mpu_write_mem` function, both function are in the [inv_mpu.c file](https://github.com/sparkfun/SparkFun_MPU-9250-DMP_Arduino_Library/blob/master/src/util/inv_mpu.c)

```
int mpu_write_mem(unsigned short mem_addr, unsigned short length,
        unsigned char *data)
{
    unsigned char tmp[2];

    if (!data)
        return -1;
    if (!st.chip_cfg.sensors)
        return -1;

    tmp[0] = (unsigned char)(mem_addr >> 8);
    tmp[1] = (unsigned char)(mem_addr & 0xFF);

    /* Check bank boundaries. */
    if (tmp[1] + length > st.hw->bank_size)
        return -1;

    if (i2c_write(st.hw->addr, st.reg->bank_sel, 2, tmp))
        return -1;
    if (i2c_write(st.hw->addr, st.reg->mem_r_w, length, data))
        return -1;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why C++ & C tags at the same time? Spam?

Comment: The lib is C lib and I write my project in C++(use class). Sorry I did not notice my question does not contain any C++.

Comment: It's undefined behavior to "cast away" const. If you are dealing with some smelly lib which doesn't use const correctness, then you have to drop const on the caller side too.

Comment: Unrelated to your question, you should replace all your magic number return codes with a proper `enum`.

Comment: Function parameter values are passed on the stack.  If the parameter values seem to change unexpectedly then ensure the stack is large enough and not overflowing.

Comment: Could be anything, and need not be in the code you have posted.  For example you appear to have some global `st`.  If members such as `hw` and `reg` are not valid the de-reference by `->` will fail in interesting ways.  We really cannot take it on trust that these are valid.  If you are inspecting these arguments in a debugger and they make no sense, it could also be because you are debugging optimised code.  How and where you made that observation is as useful a diagnostic as the observation itself.